# SVG fill from left to right with GSAP

Tags: svg, gsap

In my svg I use linearGradient to create animation for steps. But this not work in all browsers, so I want to use GSAP. I try find information about how to fill with animation, but no result. How can I do this with GSAP, with same duration and point (when finish first step begin next step )?

Example `LineGradient` animation for svg http://codepen.io/brotheryura/pen/OprOPM

Comment: Use fakeSmile to make it work elsewhere? https://leunen.me/fakesmile/

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you show any small example? because when I add it to my svg nothing to changes

Comment: The site itself has examples.

Comment: https://greensock.com/AttrPlugin and https://greensock.com/forums/topic/11573-tweening-svg-attributes/ should get you started